# MongoDB merge array of objects with value update by key

Tags: mongodb, merge, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I got stuck with aggregation, where I needed to update analytics values inside the array of objects.

I have an aggregation that produces objects like this:

```json
{
  "key": "product1",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "type": "CLICK",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "SELL",
      "value": 19.99
    }

  ]
}
```

The end of the pipeline:

```json
{
$merge: {
      into: 'analytics',
      on: ['key'],
      whenMatched: [ // <- MIGHT BE HERE SOME PREP CODE USING $$new
        {
          $replaceWith: {
            key: '$key',
            analytics: {} // <- OR HERE?
          }
        }
      ],
      whenNotMatched: 'insert'
    }
}
```

So, the issue is that this pipeline runs once an hour and collects all new data for analytics. It runs fine when adding new records by the `whenNotMatched` condition. But I need to update the "value" (summarize the old value with the new one) for each "type" if present and add new "types" if they are absent in the `analytics` array.

For example:

We have the object:

```json
{
  "key": "product1",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "type": "CLICK",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "SELL",
      "value": 19.99
    }

  ]
}
```

And after another pipeline run, we have:

```json
{
  "key": "product1",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "type": "CLICK",
      "value": 5
    },
    {
      "type": "SELL",
      "value": 29.99
    },
    {
      "type": "ABANDON",
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And upon merge we should have:

```json
{
  "key": "product1",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "type": "CLICK",
      "value": 7
    },
    {
      "type": "SELL",
      "value": 49.98
    },
    {
      "type": "ABANDON",
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complex query.

1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `$$new.analytics` array.

1.1 `$cond` - Check the iterated element's `type` exists in the existing `analytics` array. If yes, proceed to the *1.1.1* section. Otherwise, return the `newItem` object.

1.1.1. `$first` - Return the first document from the result of *1.1.1.1*.

1.1.1.1. `$map` - Iterate the matching element of the existing `analytics` array, return the element, and overwrite the existing `value` by adding with new `value`.

```
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "analytics",
      on: [
        "key"
      ],
      whenMatched: [
        {
          $replaceWith: {
            key: "$key",
            analytics: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$new.analytics",
                as: "newItem",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $in: [
                        "$$newItem.type",
                        "$analytics.type"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $first: {
                        $map: {
                          input: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$analytics",
                              cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$this.type",
                                  "$$newItem.type"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          as: "oldItem",
                          in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                              "$$newItem",
                              {
                                value: {
                                  $sum: [
                                    "$$oldItem.value",
                                    "$$newItem.value"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "$$newItem"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }
  }
```

Besides, this is another version that works with the `$let` operator:

```
{
    $merge: {
      into: "analytics",
      on: ["key"],
      whenMatched: [
        {
          $replaceWith: {
            key: "$key",
            analytics: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$new.analytics",
                as: "newItem",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $in: [
                        "$$newItem.type",
                        "$analytics.type"
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      $let: {
                        vars: {
                          oldItem: {
                            $first: {
                              $filter: {
                                input:
                                  "$analytics"
                                cond: {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$this.type",
                                    "$$newItem.type"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        in: {
                          $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$newItem",
                            {
                              value: {
                                $sum: [
                                  "$$oldItem.value",
                                  "$$newItem.value"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "$$newItem"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }
  }
```